# iOS keep app living in the background

Tags: ios, background, background-task

We have an iOS app in which some times the user is not using it so it has to remain on the background.
While the app is in the background it continues to fetch light amounts of data to keep a session alive, the problem is that the system is killing the app in 4 minutes.

We have tried:
- Activate background mode 'Background fetch' - not working.
- Put an empty sound playing in an infinite loop with mode 'Audio and AirPlay', but Apple is rejecting that version because there is no audible audio.

Any clean way to keep the app living indifinitely on the background?

Comment: Have you tried repeatedly fetching geo-location in the background instead of playing silence?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to ensure your app remains alive in the background. iOS routinely kills background apps to free up memory for more recent apps.